# Shell Script - number of minutes

Tags: shell

**Shell**

How can I write a shell script, using only shell features (and the date command), to output the number of minutes that have elapsed in the current day?

Answer (score 4):

Since `date` treats non-specifiers as literals you could use the format string to construct a simple arithmetic expression for the current number of minutes, and then evaluate the result using the shell's built-in arithmetic. For example, in `bash`

```
printf "$(( $(date '+%H * 60 + %M') ))\n"
```

If your shell does not support arithmetic, you could use an external calculator such as `bc`

```
date '+%H * 60 + %M' | bc
```

or `dc`

```
date '+%H 60 * %M + p' | dc
```

Answer (score 3):

GNU `date` and `bash`:

```
daystart_sec="$(date --date="today 00:00:00" +%s)"
now_sec="$(date +%s)"
echo $(((now_sec-daystart_sec)/60))
```

Answer (score -1):

how do I subtract the number of minutes passed in the day from the number of minutes left in the day (i.e., 1440)? So basically I want to subtract the output of the above from 1440.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please, [read the FAQ to learn how to ask questions properly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).